# DynamoDB PutItem using all heap memory - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a csv with over a million lines, I want to import all the lines into DynamoDB. I'm able to loop through the csv just fine, however, when I try to call DynamoDB PutItem on these lines, I run out of heap memory after about 18k calls.

I don't understand why this memory is being used or how I can get around this issue. Here is my code:

```
let insertIntoDynamoDB = async () => {
  const file = './file.csv';
  let index = 0;

  const readLine = createInterface({
    input: createReadStream(file),
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  readLine.on('line', async (line) => {
    let record = parse(`${line}`, {
      delimiter: ',',
      skip_empty_lines: true,
      skip_lines_with_empty_values: false
    });

    await dynamodb.putItem({
      Item: {
        "Id": {
          S: record[0][2]
        },
        "newId": {
          S: record[0][0]
        }
      },
      TableName: "My-Table-Name"
    }).promise();

    index++;
    if (index % 1000 === 0) {
      console.log(index);
    }
  });
  // halts process until all lines have been processed
  await once(readLine, 'close');

  console.log('FINAL: ' + index);
}
```

If I comment out the Dynamodb call, I can look through the file just fine and read every line. Where is this memory usage coming from? My DynamoDB write throughput is at 500, adjusting this value has no affect.

Comment: You might want to consider using `BatchWriteItem` for this. It doesn't answer the question of where the memory is going, but it's better suited for a large number of puts. At a minimum it will reduce the number of requests you are making.

Comment: I might try `BatchWriteItem`, maybe it doesn't leak memory. Only reason I haven't is it can only have 25 items at once, so it still scales linearly.

Comment: It's actually worse than that. It can only have 25 items, but it will only write up to 16MB. No matter what, you need to check the `UnprocessedItems` in the response to see if you need to make another call. So it definitely adds complexity.

Comment: Sounds like this is worth investigating/reporting at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js.

Comment: File a bug report on the github repo, hopefully something comes of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is grudging through the internet and trying to find out why DynamoDB is consuming all the heap memory, there is a github bug report found here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1777#issuecomment-339398912

Basically, the aws sdk only has 50 sockets to make http requests, if all sockets are consumed, then the events will be queued until a socket becomes available. When processing millions of requests, these sockets get consumed immediately, and then the queue builds up until it blows up the heap.

So, then how do you get around this?

1. Increase heap size
2. Increase number of sockets
3. Control how many "events" you are queueing

Options 1 and 2 are the easy way out, but do no scale. They might work for your scenario, if you are doing a 1 off thing, but if you are trying to build a robust solution, then you will wan't to go with number 3.

To do number 3, I determine the max heap size, and divide it by how large I think an "event" will be in memory. For example: I assume an updateItem event for dynamodb would be 100,000 bytes. My heap size was 4GB, so 4,000,000,000 B / 100,000 B = 40,000 events. However, I only take 50% of this many events to leave room on the heap for other processes that the node application might be doing. This percentage can be lowered/increased depending on your preference. Once I have the amount of events, I then read a line from the csv and consume an event, when the event has been completed, I release the event back into the pool. If there are no events available, then I pause the input stream to the csv until an event becomes available.

Now I can upload millions of entries to dynamodb without any worry of blowing up the heap.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean by "when the event has been completed"?  I am using C# await, so I would assume every call to "PutItemAsync" completes before the next one is tried.  However, I am also getting the out of memory error.

Comment: For me, it does about 110,000 calls to PutItemAsync and memory use goes up to 3.2GB, then I get the 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.  I have tried putting in occasional  "Thread.Sleep" to give the calls a chance to finish but nothing seems to make any difference.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have solved that immediate problem.  I was using C# Task.Run(...).Wait(), in the calling method, but have discovered this doesn't seem to actually wait!  Now I am using C# await all down the call tree, and memory has stabilised at 1.1 GB.
I don't know why this difference arises.  From the descriptions it sounds like .Wait should be more blocking than await, not less..